# How to map products to manufacturers with MAGMI

Tags: magento, import, magmi

This is probably a stupid question, but I haven’t had any luck figuring this out. How does MAGMI add products to the manufacturers_products table? Right now, it is not doing this so products are not displaying on the frontend when browsing by manufacturer unless I open the product in the backend for edit then click “Save”…which is obviously not a solution. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

This manufacturers_product table is surely an extension specific table. so not a magento table. clicking "save" on product will call the extension that will identify the manufacturer of the product & put it in extension specific table. so if you want magmi to fill an extension specific table, you need to have a specific plugin that would do this job.